# How to prove that the inverse of a persymmetric matrix is also persymmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, alternative-proof

An exercise in a textbook I'm using to brush up on my linear algebra asks to prove that the inverse of a persymmetric matrix is also persymmetric. I have a colleague's old notes in front of me with a solution, but I can't understand his reasoning. It states:

> Let $A_S$ denote the persymmetric matrix. Then $A = SA_S = A_SS$, where $A$ is the anti-diagonal identity matrix (i.e.: the identity matrix rotated 90°).
>
> $$(SA_S)^{-1} = A_S^{-1}S^{-1}$$
>
> In a previous question, we have proven that $A = A^{-1}$ ($A^2 = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, and thus $A^2 = AA = I$, and so multiplying both sides by the inverse $A^{-1}$ we have $A = A^{-1}$). Thus:
>
> $$(SA_S)^{-1} = A_S^{-1}S^{-1} = A_S^{-1}S$$
>
> Therefore we need only prove $A_S^{-1}$ is symmetric. In a previous question we proved the transpose of the inverse of a matrix is equivalent to the inverse of its transpose, so $(A_S^{-1})^T = (A_S^T)^{-1}$. Since we know $A_S^T = A_S$, $(A_S^T)^{-1} = A_S^{-1}$, therefore $A_S^{-1}$ is symmetric. **QED.**

I can't follow several bits of reasoning in this answer.

1. First of all, I don't see how the second equation follows from the setup--how does $A = A^{-1}$ tell us that $A_S^{-1}S^{-1} = A_S^{-1}S$?
2. Why is proving $A_S^{-1}$ to be symmetric sufficient to prove $A_S^{-1}$ is persymmetric?
3. The author claims $A_S^T = A_S$, which would be true for a symmetric matrix, but not a persymmetric one (it is true that the transpose of a persymmetric matrix is also persymmetric). What is the basis for this claim?

It's also possible that my colleague's answer is incorrect. I have an idea that perhaps using the facts that $A$ rotated by 90° is $I$ and $A_S$ rotated by 90° is a symmetric matrix in order to tackle the proof, but I'm stuck on the specifics.

Can someone either explain my colleague's answer, give me a hint on how to prove this statement, or provide a proof of their own?

Comment: Yes, I think the answer has some typos in which $A_S$ is replaced by $A$. But the general idea might work.

Comment: For reference to others (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persymmetric_matrix). And because Wikipedia lists two different definitions, from the given proof it is clear here it is about the first definition.

Comment: Let us look at the computation of the inverse using the minors. Since the matrix is symmetric with respect to the antidiagonal, the minors of two components that are symmetric with respect to the antidiagonal should be the same. Therefore the matrix of the cofactors is persymmetric too. Now we divide by the determinant everywhere. This preserves persymmetry. Finally we transpose. But if a matrix symmetric with respect to the antidiagonal is transposed, the symmetry with respect to the antidiagonal is preserved.

Comment: Another Wikipedia article, [Exchange matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix), denotes the identity matrix rotated $90^\circ$ with the symbol $J$. Then it says persymmetry of $X$ is equivalent with $XJ=JX^T$. This is persymmetry in the sense that $x_{i,j} = x_{n+1-j,n+1-i}$ for all $i$ and $j$, which is the same as defining a matrix $X$ as persymmetric iff it is the rotation by $90^\circ$ of a symmetric matrix. On the other hand, $XJ=JX$ (without transpose) is stated to be equivalent with $X$ being centrosymmetric, not persymmetric.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be a nonsingular persymmetric matrix, and let $J$ be the exchange matrix.  The condition of persymmetry, under the usual definition (see, e.g., Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* or Golub and Van Loan's *Matrix Computations*), can be expressed as $A=JA^TJ$.  Consequently, we have that

$A^{-1}=J^{-1}(A^T)^{-1}J^{-1}=J(A^{-1})^TJ$

where we've used basic facts about the inverse of a nonsingular matrix product, the fact that $J$ is involutory (i.e., is its own inverse), and that $(A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T$.  This shows that $A^{-1}$ is persymmetric.